# How to query only old and duplicate data from a database in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to query my database to pull only duplicate/old data to write to a scratch section in excel (Using a macro passing SQL to the DB).

For now, I'm currently testing in Access alone to only filter out the old data.

First, I'm trying to filter my database by a specifed WorkOrder, RunNumber, and Row.

The code below only filters by Work Order, RunNumber, and Row. ...but SQL doesn't like when I tack on a 2nd AND statement;  so this currently isn't working.

```
SELECT *
FROM DataPoints
WHERE (((DataPoints.[WorkOrder])=[WO2]) AND ((DataPoints.[RunNumber])=6) AND ((DataPoints.[Row]=1)
```

Once I figure that portion out....

Then if there is only 1 entry with specified WorkOrder, RunNumber, and Row, then I want filter it out. (its not needed in the scratch section, because its data is already written to the main section of my report)

If there are 2 or more entries with said criteria(WO, RN, and Row), then I want to filter out the newest entry based on RunDate and RunTime, and only keep all older entries.

For instance, in the clip below.  The only item remaining in my filtered query will be the top entry with the timestamp 11:47:00AM.

[image: Sample data snippet].

Are there any recommended commands to complete this problem?  Any ideas are helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to surround everything with parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something along the lines of the following:

```
select t.* 
from datapoints t 
where 
    t.workorder = [WO2] and 
    t.runnumber = 6 and 
    t.row = 1 and
    exists
    (
        select 1 
        from datapoints u 
        where 
            u.workorder = t.workorder and
            u.runnumber = t.runnumber and
            u.row = t.row and
            (u.rundate > t.rundate or (u.rundate = t.rundate and u.runtime > t.runtime))
    )
```

Here, if the correlated subquery within the `where` clause finds a record with the same `workorder`, `runnumber` and `row`, but with either a later `rundate` or the same `rundate` and a later `runtime`, then the record is returned by the main query.

Comment: You're the man.  This works perfectly.  Thank you for your help twice!

Answer (score 0):

You need two more )'s at the end of your code snippet.  Or you can delete the parentheses completely in this example, MS Access will ad them back in as it deems necessary.

M.S. Access SQL can be tricky as it is not standards compliant and either doesn't allow for super complex queries, or it needs an ugly work around, like having a parentheses nesting nightmare when trying to join more than two tables.

For these reasons, I suggest using multiple Access queries to produce your results.